# How to do a fallthrough in T_SQl case

Tags: t-sql

Given below, is just part of a big query.
Is there a better way of writing this ?

```
select @a=
    case @pcono
    when '00' then sum(ptdbal00)
    when '01' then sum(ptdbal00)+ sum(ptdbal01)
    when '02' then sum(ptdbal00)+ sum(ptdbal01)+sum(ptdbal02)
    ...



 end 

from accthist
where ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Better" is rather subjective, but different, yes;

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ptdbal00 n, 0 m FROM test UNION ALL 
  SELECT ptdbal01 n, 1 m FROM test UNION ALL 
  SELECT ptdbal02 n, 2 m FROM test UNION ALL 
  SELECT ptdbal03 n, 3 m FROM test UNION ALL 
  SELECT ptdbal04 n, 4 m FROM test UNION ALL 
  SELECT ptdbal05 n, 5 m FROM test
)
SELECT @a=SUM(n) FROM cte WHERE m<=@pcono
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de1ed/1).

To be honest though, it looks like you may need to look at normalizing the database.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I suspect it may if the row is very long and it fetches un-necessary columns from disk, however I can't see any obvious ill effect in the query plan for reasonably short row lengths. The best is always to test with real data though.

Answer (score 0):

how about this, I think performance is the same, but it is easier to read and maintain:

```
select @a=sum(ptdbal00) + 
    case when @pcono >= '01' then sum(ptdbal01) else 0 end+
    case when @pcono >= '02' then sum(ptdbal02) else 0 end+
    case when @pcono >= '03' then sum(ptdbal03) else 0 end+
    case when @pcono >= '04' then sum(ptdbal04) else 0 end+
    case when @pcono >= '05' then sum(ptdbal05) else 0 end+
    case when @pcono >= '06' then sum(ptdbal06) else 0 end+
    ...



 end 

from accthist
where ...
```